# ls and du disagree about file size, by a few orders of magnitude

Tags: ubuntu, ls, disk-usage

Does anyone understand why I might get these results? Note the discrepency in file size between the two commands below:

```
$ ls -lh gauss_landmarks_0000.npy 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dparks dparks 1.1G Aug 16 12:43 gauss_landmarks_0000.npy

$ du -h gauss_landmarks_0000.npy 
20M     gauss_landmarks_0000.npy
```

This occurs on the machine shown below:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

The results on my own linux mint laptop appear as expected:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: LinuxMint
Description:    Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia
Release:        18.3
Codename:       sylvia
```

Comment: can you share the result of `blockdev --getbsz /dev/<partition>`

Comment: 4096 on blockdev. But it looks like the sparse file answer pegged it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is probably a sparse file. That means that not all blocks are allocated and the file uses much less space than the file size suggests. On read the missing blocks will read as zero.

You can also use the `-s` option to `ls` to see the allocated size, it should be the same as the size reported by `du`.

**Edit**

If you have a file that you know or suspects contains many zero bytes but is not sparse, you can use `cp --sparse=always` to make it sparse, potentially saving a lot of disk space.

```
cp --sparse=always -p file new_file
```

Comment: Brilliant, `ls -s` does indeed show 20M. The data stored in that file is indeed quite sparse, so this makes perfect sense. I never knew the filesystem made provisions for sparse files. Thanks! This was a `zfs` filesystem, FYI.

Comment: My laptop file system is `ext4`, where I don't see this occur. So it appears to be a features of `zfs` that isn't in a typical configuration of `ext4` fs.

Comment: Sparse files have been supported since the early days of Unix.  Every native Linux file system should support them.

Comment: Interesting. `ls -sh gauss_landmarks_0000.npy` shows 1.1GB on my linux mint based ext4 FS which sits on a LVM controlled volume. I'll read up on this in any case.

Comment: It appears that the file being sparse is indeed not dependent on the filesystem as RalfFriedl says. The discrepancy is that the files were transferred through AWS S3 which didn't maintain the file sparsity over that channel.  Thanks again!

Comment: I added a command to make the file sparse again.

Answer (score 0):

In your case the difference was indeed caused by a sparse file as explained in the other answer.

Another source of differences when an entire directory is involved are **hard links**. By default `du` does not count hard links multiple times, which can result in `du` reporting much less then what e.g. `ll -sh` shows.

To check whether hard links are involved you can run `du -l` so that it also counts hard links many times, or you can run `ll -i <DIR> | sort`. The left column will show the inode id, and if it is repeated the files are hard links of each other.