# du reports directory size as much smaller than the sum of its contents

Tags: ls, disk-usage

I have a directory `~/D` that I'd like to find the size of. using `du -c ~/D/*` gives `26880`. However, if I run `ls -l ~/D`, then I can clearly see that the individual files add up to much more than `26880`. In fact, if I inspect a single file, `du` get's that wrong as well. The last line of the output of `du ~/D/*` gives

```
256 /home/me/D/lastFile.bin
```

while the last line of `ls -l ~/D` is

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 me myGroup 3124 Aug 24 21:58 lastFile.bin
```

where `256` clearly does not equal `3124`. What gives? Does it matter that these are binary files?

**Edit:** This is not a duplicate of a question regarding the difference between `du` and `df`; `df` does not seem to be able to offer me anything in this situation

**Edit:** `stat -c %s ~/D/lastFile.bin` agrees with the output of `ls -l`

Comment: A related question is https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/464496/ .

Answer (score 1):

From the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/du.1.html):

> ```
>    Display values are in units of the first available SIZE from
>    --block-size, and the DU_BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE and BLOCKSIZE
>    environment variables.  Otherwise, units default to 1024 bytes (or
>    512 if POSIXLY_CORRECT is set).
> ```

So, 256 kB (or 128 kB, if you happen to be POSIXly-correct) gives plenty of room for a couple of 3124-byte files.

With GNU `du`, you can use the `-B` option to set the unit size for the output, either use `-B1` or `-b` (equal to `-B1 --apparent-size`) to get the size in bytes, which is what `ls` prints by default.

The mismatches you might actually see may be quirks of the filesystem bookkeeping, at least mostly the fact that files are allocated in full blocks. For example, on an `ext4` filesystem, a `100000`-byte file actually takes `102400` bytes, since it's allocated in blocks of `4096` bytes. That's what `du` shows on my system.

`--apparent-size` makes `du` count just the data size of the files, not the overhead.